# Supress information in mysql prompt

Tags: mysql, verbosity

I ran the query in mysql prompt , I need to supress the "1 row in set (0.00 sec)" in output prompt. How I can do it

```
mysql> select concat( " Total Records in Transaction Table : ", count(*) ) from transaction_process ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat( " Total Records in Transaction Table : ", count(*) ) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Total Records in Transaction Table : 0                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the `mysql` client with the `-s` or `--silent` option.